# Elementary inquiry about C++ (SDL2 library)

Tags: c++, variables, window, sdl-2

I'm fairly new to programming, so this question will probably be basic. I'm writing a very basic program in C++ with the SDL2 library (in Visual Studio 2013). When I was writing it, I came across a problem. I wrote the following:

```
    int controles(){
        //declare actions that will happen when a key is pressed
        const Uint8 * estado = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
        if (estado[SDL_SCANCODE_UP]){ y--; SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(ventana); }
        if (estado[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN]){ y++; SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(ventana); }
        return 0;
    }
```

The problem is that I need to update the window surface after the value of *y* is modified, but I get an error because *ventana*, the name of the window, is defined in another function. I tried to define *ventana* globally, but the program won't work then. I then thought the following; write a **goto** statement in *graficos*, the function where *ventana* is defined, in order to skip every other statement in that function, except for the one that updates the window surface. However, when I did that, the program doesn't even compile:

```
int graficos(int caso){
    if (caso == 1) {goto reload;} //skip to reload if (1)
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO); //load SDL
    //load graphics in memory
    SDL_Window * ventana = SDL_CreateWindow("ventana", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);
    SDL_Surface * superficie = SDL_GetWindowSurface(ventana);
    SDL_Surface * pantallainicio = SDL_LoadBMP("pantallainicio.bmp");
    SDL_Surface * paleta = SDL_LoadBMP("paleta.bmp");
    SDL_Rect rpantallainicio = { 0, 0, 640, 480 };
    SDL_Rect rpaleta = { x, y, 16, 16 };
    //render graphics
    SDL_BlitSurface(pantallainicio, NULL, superficie, &rpantallainicio);
    SDL_BlitSurface(paleta, NULL, superficie, &rpaleta);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(ventana);
    reload:SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(ventana);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
error C4533: initialization of 'rpaleta' is skipped by 'goto reload'
error C4533: initialization of 'rpantallainicio' is skipped by 'goto reload'
```

I hope I explained my issue well enough. What can I do?  Is there a way to fix this? Or can I reference *ventana* in some other way? This issue might be very basic, sorry for that, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this issue by simply not using goto at all - use a sub-function instead. Also, extract the variable ventana, as you need it to be stored and usable by graficos whenever.

```
void init()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO); //load SDL
    //load graphics in memory
    ventana = SDL_CreateWindow("ventana", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,       SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);
    SDL_Surface * superficie = SDL_GetWindowSurface(ventana);
    SDL_Surface * pantallainicio = SDL_LoadBMP("pantallainicio.bmp");
    SDL_Surface * paleta = SDL_LoadBMP("paleta.bmp");
    SDL_Rect rpantallainicio = { 0, 0, 640, 480 };
    SDL_Rect rpaleta = { x, y, 16, 16 };
    //render graphics
    SDL_BlitSurface(pantallainicio, NULL, superficie, &rpantallainicio);
    SDL_BlitSurface(paleta, NULL, superficie, &rpaleta);
}

int graficos(int caso)
{
    if (caso != 1) { init(); } //skip to reload if (1)
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(ventana);
    return 0;
}

SDL_Window * ventana;
```

Use of goto should *generally* be avoided. Use subroutines or other alternatives where possible. Here, the code does exactly the same thing as originally intended, but the "extra" flow that occurs when caso is not 1 is wrapped in its own subroutine named 'init'.

Comment: Thank you! However when I tried what you said, I get that _ventana_ is undeclared. Am I missing something?

Comment: You'll need to store ventana as a field in the class then. I'm updating the code snippet to reflect that.